# How to set cross domain cookie in Koa

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, axios

I have a Koa and GraphQL API with an authentication resolver which adds sets an auth token to the response cookies.

My API runs on `http://localhost:3000` and my front end runs on `http://localhost:3001`. In order to make this work, I needed to add `withCredentials` flag to my API request as well as configure my Koa/Cors options with `{ origin: false, credentials: true }`. Without these settings I would get a CORS error which I find confusing because they are both on `localhost` so technically the same domain...?

There will be multiple front ends using this API and will need to authenticate and get the auth token set in the cookie. When I spoof my domain name as `http://app1.dev` & `http://app2.dev`, both calling the API on `http://localhost:3000`, the auth token gets set in the response cookies but the browser does not store the cookie like it did when everything was `localhost`.

On my API, I am using `@koa/cors` for my configuring my cors and then set the following:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: false, credentials: true }))
```

On my front end react app, I have a request function which I use for all my GraphQL queries:

```
const request = query => {

  const request = axios.create({
    baseURL: apiUrl,
    headers: {'X-apikey': apiKey},
    withCredentials: true,
  });

  return request.post('/graphql', { query })
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(console.error)
}
```

Why are the cookies not getting set in the browser?

EDIT: Updated my axios request to create instance of axios and attempting to set withCredentials. I am still not seeing the credentials param in my request in dev tools though. I suspect this could be the issue?